# call php function with arguments using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php file `func.php` where I defined many functions let's say :

```
<? php 
function func1($data){
return $data+1;
}
?>
```

I want to call the `function func1` using **ajax**. thank you for your help

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the error you are getting?  At first glance I would say that you should pass some value in using AJAX and then your PHP script will pick that value up and run the desired function using say....a `switch` statement.

Comment: Do all the functions accept one parameter?

Comment: @geomagas ,no I have functions with more than one parameter

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can't call a PHP function directly from an AJAX call, but you can do this:

PHP:

```
<? php 
    function func1($data){
        return $data+1;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['callFunc1'])) {
        echo func1($_POST['callFunc1']);
    }
?>
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myFunctions.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { "callFunc1": "1"},
    success: function(response) { alert(response); }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You should call your php script through an ajax request, using jQuery like:

**Javascript:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  data: { param1: "value1", param2: "value2" },
  type: "GET",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  // your code goes here
});
```

You could give your parameters through data property of ajax object.

**Php**

```
// you can do isset check before 
$param1 = $_GET['param1'];
$param2 = $_GET['param2'];

// validate // sanitize // save to db // blah blah // do something with params
```

More information you could get from jQuery.ajax() function description from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Well, this sends parameters to the PHP script, but how do you feed them into the PHP function in that script?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more complicated, but I will try to shrink it down to the basics.

You will need some kind of interface (a convention, basically) between the caller and your script. Two are the main concerns here:

1. The way your script understands what needs to be called and with what arguments. Let's say you decide to use a `GET` request for calling a function. The function name could be in a `func` field and the arguments in an `args` one, as a string separated by `;`. In other words, calling `funcFoo(5,'bar')` would be done by requesting `func.php?func=func1&args=5;bar`.
2. The way in which the caller receives (and understands) the return value. Since your requirements are js-oriented, a JSON approach would be highly appropriate.

Add the following code along with your functions:

```
if(isset($_GET['func']))
  {
  $func=$_GET['func'];
  if(function_exists($func))
    {
    $args=(isset($_GET['args'])?explode(';',$_GET['args']):array());
    $result=call_user_func_array($func,$args);
    }
  else
    $result=array('error'=>"Unknown Function $func!");
  }
else
  $result=array('error'=>"No function name provided!");
echo json_encode($result);
```

However, your functions should also be changed to meet the new requirements. Since there's no way of telling how many arguments the caller will supply, a function should be designed to accept no mandatory arguments and check for the supplied ones itself. Also, it should always return an array in order to be `json_encode`d before it is returned to the caller.

Your example function, for instance, should look something like this:

```
function func1(){
    $data=func_get_args();
    if(count($data)) // at least one -- rest will be ignored
      return $data[0]+1;
    else
      return array('error'=>__FUNCTION__."() expects an argument!");
}
```

**Be aware though**: This is just a skeleton to get you started with the whole concept. A lot more care should be taken for both *fault tolerance* and *security*. But that's another topic's subject.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can !

here my code :

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: { kode: $(this).val(), func: 'my_func' },

        success: function(response) {
            //any success method here
        }
    });
```

and here the code in php to receive what function to call.

```
$post = (object) $_POST;
if(!$post)
    return false;

$func = $post->func;
return $func($post);

function my_func($post) {    

    $json['any_data'] = false;

    if($post->kode == 'ND'){               
        $json['any_data'] = 'ND-'.date('Y');
    }

    echo json_encode($json);

}
```

Hope it help you out bro...  :D